# How can we perfrom pre fitted standard scalar inverse transform on y variable in pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to create pipeline which will inverse transform the y variable after model prediction

I have 3 pickle files:

- X variable scalar transform pre fitted object  :-X sclr
- Y variable scalar transform pre fitted object  :-Y sclr
- svr model object:-  model

I imported it to python and now I want create pipeline using this file where input data will get scalar transformed by  Xsclr parameter----> then model prediction will happen and then output of model will get inverse transformed  using Y sclr  object parameter

The implementation would look like

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[(StandardScaler(), Xsclr),
                       (SVR(), model),
                       (InverseTransformer(), Ysclr)]
)
```

I actually I wants to convert this pipeline to  ONNX format... Afterwords.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in with standard scikit-learn. Scikit-learn Pipelines are not designed to transform y/target variable, they are designed to only work on X/features.

Answer (score 0):

Functionality for transforming regression targets exists, in the `TransformedTargetRegressor` class; see [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html#sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor).  With prefitted model and scaler, you might be able to set the "fitted" attributes `regressor_` and `transformer_`.